# People tagging in Newsfeed not sending email notifcation

Tags: email, newsfeed, tagging

I was under the impression that if a user was tagged in the Newsfeed i.e. @carl that SharePoint 2013 would send a email to Carl telling him he was mentioned in the Newsfeed. I cant figure out where this functionality lives in any setting. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment to clarify but I assume you have it connected to Exchange and other emails are being delivered e.g. when you reply to someone's comment or when you subscribe to changes in a file that is then changed?

Check your Exchange for security and delivering of anonymous messages - adding sharepoint's address to Exchange so it's not being discarded as spam.

What do you have set as in Central Administration -> System Settings -> Configure Outgoing Email Settings? Did you allow Exchange to relay messages from that address?

Or you can install SMTP server on your machine and have it send that way
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc263462.aspx

Comment: Yes. Other emails go through just fine. File changes and library modification emails go through. Out going email is configured. I'll check the spam software but I'm not sure why those notifications would go through but tagging notifications wont. @jurajb

Comment: it might be the authentication on Exchange afterall - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/89f167bd-b2a2-4fc1-9c2e-ddf4884e3dec/newsfeed-notifications-not-being-sent-by-email